# Queue not created in ActiveMq

Tags: java, glassfish, jms, activemq-classic

I am a newbie to this so forgive me if my mistake seems stupid.I am using active mq with glassfish and eclipse. I have created JMS resources in glass fish such as Destination Resources and Connection Factories. Active Mq is running and I have deployed message driven bean on glassfish and no exceptions occur but i can't find my Queue on active mq and neither is the message printed on console.

I am basically using example given on here : https://www.javatpoint.com/message-driven-bean

```
public class MessageSender {

public static void sendMessage() throws JMSException, NamingException {


    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();

    QueueConnectionFactory f = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("jms/myQueueConnectionFactory");
    QueueConnection connection = f.createQueueConnection();
    connection.start();

    QueueSession ses = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    Queue t = (Queue) ctx.lookup("jms/myQueue");

    QueueSender sender = ses.createSender(t);

    TextMessage message=ses.createTextMessage("Hello !!! Welcome to the world of ActiveMQ.");  
    sender.send(message);

    connection.close();

}
```

}

```
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "jms/myQueue")
```

public class MessageReceiver implements MessageListener {

```
/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public MessageReceiver() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see MessageListener#onMessage(Message)
 */
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     TextMessage m=(TextMessage) message;  
     try{  
     System.out.println("message received: "+m.getText());  
     }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  

}
```

}[image]

[image]

Comment: after some searching I found out that I may need to connect ActiveMq with Glassfish. So if anyone knows any good tutorial about it. Please share. Thank You

Comment: it was a nice tutorial and it works 
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/connect-glassfish-3-to-external.html

Comment: If you've solved the problem you should "answer" your own question here and mark it as such so it's clear for others who might run into this issue in the future. Or you can just delete the question.